# How to use external python modules with microsoft azure

Tags: python, azure, flask, sympy

I am trying to use SymPy module in python, implemented on the Microsoft Azure platform, to no avail. This is the first of a few modules I want to use but I am finding it very difficult to find a step by step guide on how to implement any external python modules in Microsoft Azure. Has anybody had any experience with this that could offer advice? I have tried downloading the source from github and putting it in the same folder that contains my app folder. Incidentally I have set up a Flask app within azure, and cloned the app to a local folder where I seen the flask folder so thought that I could put the Sympy folder in there and call it but that hasn't worked. Help!!